# Understanding the relation between pressure, ideal gas and, volume

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, evaporation, volume

I was given the following formula which is used for ideal gasses:
$$pV = nRT$$

where:

- p:pressure
- V: volume
- n: number of moles
- R: gasconstant
- T: temperature

now when speaking about vaporpressure curves like this one:

[image]

You can change the formula like so:
$$ pV = NkT = nRT = \frac{m}{M}RT$$

where:

- V: vapor volume
- m: mass of the vapor
- M: molar mass of the particles
- N: number of particles which are in vapor state
- n: amount of moles

Based on the previous formula you can calculate the pressure like this:
$$\rho(T) = \frac{pM}{RT}$$

Now I would like to know where the volume is in this final formula to calculate the pressure?

Is this formula still applicable: $p = \frac{nRT}{V}$ ? (If not, in which cases is it?) This formula seems much easier to me.

Comment: Please define $\rho$

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is that
\begin{equation}
\rho \propto 1/V
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
m/\rho = 1/V
\end{equation}
with this knowledge you should be able to see how your final equation relates to 
\begin{equation}
pV = nRT
\end{equation}